# Laravel 5.3 create login/auth actions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel 5.3 and already found out that the old auth controller has been moved to the core (Illuminate...). For unauthenticated users there is a "unauthenticated" function in App\Exceptions\Handler.php which is called when an unathenticated user throws an "authentication"-exception.

However I didn't found out where to put a function which should be called everytime a user *successfully* logs in or has been authenticated *successfully* by the remember token. In my example this function should do some things like log ip etc.

Can you help me where to put such a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done using this command in command prompt.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Comment: I already did this and the authentication system (register, login...) is working pretty fine. I just want to add a custom function which is called everytime someone logs in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, there is no "unauthenticated" function in App\Exceptions\Handler.php of Laravel 5.3

You should look into [authorization actions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates)

Laravel 5.3 comes with the Auth scafolding pre-packaged.

```
PROJECT/app/Http/Controllers/Auth
```

Comment: This is the function from my Handler.php:

`protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

  
  echo $request;

        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }`

Comment: That's a custom function I suppose? I just created a simple project for fun with  Laravel Framework version 5.3.26 and it doesn't have that function. But that's not the problem.

Comment: You may need to create an event listener that listens to a https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5

Comment: I already had a look at LoginController.php in /app/Http/Controllers/Auth but I don't know how to put an action there which is executed everytime a user logged in successfully :(

Comment: The answer with the event listener looks good, I'll take a look. Thanks

Comment: the "unauthenticated"-function isn't a custom one. it's part of laravel 5.3 or the authentication package ("make:auth")

Comment: I am at work, but I have a working example at home. If you don't get an answer soon, let me know but the event  listening is the fastest way to go

Answer (score 0):

In 5.3 I just modified the success and failure actions for the login using the out-of-the-box authentication.  This Gist might be helpful to you.  It actually explains step-by-step how to login using api/login and pass back a token to a mobile platform.  Then you can subsequently call back to all of your API's with the token.  I modified the returns to recognize the Json request header and send back the user as json.

Here is the information that might help you.  [Laravel API Token Help](https://gistlog.co/almenke/ed1f32e6c9fafc7d4203f50369a78568)

Comment: Steps 7 & 8 should help for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom auth solution.

```
class AdminsController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required']);

        if(!Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'Could not log you in!']);
        }

        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');

    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('index');
    }
}
```

And in the routes.php :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {

    Route::get('/admin/login', [
        'uses' => 'AdminsController@getLogin',
        'as' => 'admin.login'
    ]);

    Route::post('/admin/login', [
        'uses' => 'AdminsController@postLogin',
        'as' => 'admin.login'
    ]);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin/logout', [
        'uses' => 'AdminsController@getLogout',
        'as' => 'admin.logout'
    ]);
});
```

Hope you get around with this code and that it was helpful.